# FOREach loop for two ArrayList in same time c#

Tags: c#

I want to loop two file line in same time by foreach

```
foreach (string i in username_list && string j in password_list)
Console.WriteLine(i+"---"+j);
```

Comment: Your question asks about looping over two of the same file lines in two loops. But your code sample is looping in two different lists -- `username_list` and `password_list`. Could you edit your question and clarify exactly what you are trying to do here?

Comment: why dont you just create User Class with Name and Password property  and than loop the list of the objects of User class?

Comment: StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("pass.txt");
                line = sr.ReadLine();

                while (line != null)
                {
                    password_list.Add(line);
                    line = sr.ReadLine();
                }
                sr.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("pass.txt couldn't be found: " + err.Message);

            }

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code example directly to your question. Don't post it as a comment.

Comment: String line;
            ArrayList username_list = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList password_list = new ArrayList();
            try
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("user.txt");
                line = sr.ReadLine();
                while (line != null)
                {
                    username_list.Add(line);
                    line = sr.ReadLine();
                }
                sr.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {

Comment: 1) Don't use `ArrayList`. Use a generic `List<T>`. 2) Create a class to group related data. Don't iterate over two lists and rely on indexes matching up between the two lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you necessarily want to Use Foreach, you have to Zip the two collections first.

```
 foreach (var (username, password) in username_list.Zip(password_list, (x, y) => (x, y))
     Console.WriteLine($"{user} {password}");
```

Zipping has nothing todo with Zip-Files here, just with a regular zipper (take one from the left, one from the right, and join them).

Comment: Using C#7 tuples instead of anonymous types will be more effective.

Comment: how to use zip <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />

Comment: I'm not sure why this was down voted. Zip is the correct approach.

Comment: thanks for all it is work with  List<T> not ArrayList